# How can I update values in a dictionary that is stored by a list, from strings to integers in Python?

Tags: python

```
ct_dict = {
    'fr': ['55410', '94560', '52533', '63040', '52533'],
    'de': ['73546', '64090', '60938', '75648', '60938']}
```

How can i change the values inside the dictionary from string to integer? For example: `['55410', '94560', '52533', '63040', '52533']` to `[55410, 94560, 52533, 63040, 52533]`

I tried using 2 for loops with update method but got this error:

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Code that got the error:

```
for i in ct_dict:
  for j in ct_dict[i]:
    ct_dict.update({j:int(j)})
```

Comment: Use a dict comprehension instead. Or put the result into a new dict instead of `ct_dict`.

Comment: The values are **lists of strings**, not strings themselves, so you'll need to rethink your approach. (Although, `ct_dict.update({j: ...})` is wrong anyway.) Think about how to [convert a list of strings to int](/q/7368789/4518341).

Comment: @luk2302 That's not necessary at all. OP's just going about this wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The keys of `ct_dict` are `i`, not `j`, so you shouldn't use `j` in the `.update()` method.

But if you're just updating one key, just assign to that key rather than using `.update()`.

You need to map `int()` over all the elements of the list.

```
for i, vals in ct_dict.items():
    ct_dict[i] = list(map(int, vals))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to update the dictionary, just change the values in the lists directly:

```
for nums in ct_dict.values(): 
    nums[:] = map(int,nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error because you're trying to modify the dict you're using as a reference in the for loop, while the loop is executing, and you can't do that.

**Solution**

Assuming:

```
ct_dict = {
        "fr": ["55410", "94560", "52533", "63040", "52533"],
        "de": ["73546", "64090", "60938", "75648", "60938"],
    }
```

Best option is use to dict comprehension:

```
new_ct_dict = {key: [int(i) for i in values] for key, values in ct_dict.items()}
```

But you can also do:

```
new_ct_dict = {}
for key, values in ct_dict.items():
    new_ct_dict.update({key: []})
    for i in values:
        new_ct_dict[key].append(int(i))
```

Result:

```
{'fr': [55410, 94560, 52533, 63040, 52533], 'de': [73546, 64090, 60938, 75648, 60938]}
```

Comment: Although this works, this is not a good answer - it doesn't really address OP's problem other than avoiding it with alternative code and provide no explanation of why this works and why what OP did wsould not. Have a look at [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: `new_ct_dict.update({key: []})` should be `new_ct_dict[key] = []`

Comment: You don't need to create a new dict when you can update the existing one, like in [Barmar's answer](/a/76377300/4518341).

Answer (score 0):

**Use a `for` loop and a list comprehension:**

```py
my_dict = {'fr': ['55410', '94560', '52533', '63040', '52533'], 'de': ['73546', '64090', '60938', '75648', '60938']}
new_dict = {}

for key, val in my_dict.items():
    new_dict[key] = [int(item) for item in val]

print(new_dict)  # {'fr': [55410, 94560, 52533, 63040, 52533], 'de': [73546, 64090, 60938, 75648, 60938]}
```

Or, if you'd rather not create another `dict`:

```
my_dict = {'fr': ['55410', '94560', '52533', '63040', '52533'], 'de': ['73546', '64090', '60938', '75648', '60938']}

for key, val in my_dict.items():
    my_dict[key] = [int(item) for item in val]

print(my_dict)  # {'fr': [55410, 94560, 52533, 63040, 52533], 'de': [73546, 64090, 60938, 75648, 60938]}
```

For more on list comprehensions see: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp

For more on the `dict.items()` method see: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_items.asp

Comment: Why are you creating a new dict?

Comment: But if you do create a new dict, a dict comprehension would be cleaner.

Comment: But less understandable...

Comment: @wjandrea I updated my answer with an option that doesn't make a new dict.